# Restoring Consumable Purchases Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-purchase, restore

I’m using Unity. I want mobile users to be able to restore **consumable** items if they reinstall the app or if they change phones.
I would rather they don’t have to login specifically to my app and I don’t want to store anything private like an email.

So for example a user buys 5 coins, uses 2 then upgrades their phone.
When re-open the app they have 3 coins left. Simple.

There seem to be various systems to do this but the main seem to be:

- Firestore.
- Unity economy.

I’m wondering has anyone implemented such a system? What did they use and what do we have to be careful with before we implement?
With Firestone, there are anonymous users but they gets deleted on reinstall.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Question is why would you want to restore consumables like coins. If I move to the new phone I would rather have all my progress restored, instead of starting at lvl 1 with bunch of premium currency. It also seems to be the standard. If you still want to do it though, I've seen one mobile game that generated recovery codes, that you could enter on new device. Also, I think on iOS you can use key/value pair without being logged to game center.

Comment: I'm going to annoy a lot of users if I don't restore purchases.

Comment: If you don't restore non-consumable purchases. Keep in mind, that if you restore your whole game state, your consumables will be inside of it. For eg. if user paid 10 coins to increase level by 2, restoring player level will reflect his purchase. And I don't know how would you do it otherwise. Keep game state, but somehow remove all stuff bought by premium currency then give it back? It creates lots of problems, like why would you reset players purchases for premium currency? Because if you don't, I could just reinstall game for endless premium currency.

Comment: Sorry but your making extrapolations and strawmannirg statements I never made. I just want to restore an integer. If you can't help me then please let someone else answer.

Comment: Well, then your question title and constant referring to consumables is misleading. If you want to save int and load it on a different device, you just look for save/load system. You aren't restoring anything, because it stops making sense at the very moment user spends his currency for the first time. If he buys 5 spends 2, you aren't going to restore him 5 for a total 7. Unless you claim, that restoring purchase is simply stating, that he has 3 left, then we have different definitions of what is restoring.

Comment: I'm saying about consumables, because that's what I gathered from the question, and wished you don't make any mistakes. If you look for save system, that's fine, just edit your question.

Comment: Can you stop contradicting statements I haven't made? The question is not misleading at all. Firstly, the integer represents the consumable. Secondly it needs to be stored on a server. Thirdly I never said I would consumed coins (you said that, not me), I want to restore remaining coins. Hence the term consumable.